# something problem on alertdialog flutter, you can help me?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'modalBarrierDismissLabel' was called on null.
```

This is code

```
....

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "Booking Antrian",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.indigo,
            onPressed: () {
              createInterstitialAd()
                ..load()
                ..show();
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "Keluar",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.green,
            onPressed: () {
              createInterstitialAd()
                ..load()
                ..show();
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "About",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.pink,
            onPressed: () {
              createInterstitialAd()
                ..load()
                ..show();
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Alert with Buttons'),
            onPressed: () => _onAlertButtonsPressed(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

...

_onAlertButtonsPressed(context) {
  Alert(
    context: context,
    //image: Image.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
    image: Image.asset(
      'assets/images/watermark.jpg',
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
    ),
    title: "RE",
    desc: "Halo.. ",
    buttons: [
      DialogButton(
        child: Text(
          "Close",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        color: Color.fromRGBO(231, 76, 60, 10),
      ),
      DialogButton(
        child: Text(
          "Share",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 179, 134, 1.0),
      ),
    ],
  ).show();
}

...
```

Comment: please post Alert widget

Answer (score 0):

in your app delegates add this:

```
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
```

So in your main MaterialApp Widget:

```
MaterialApp(
...
localizationsDelegates: [
          // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization of basic text for Cupertino widgets
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
        ],
)
```